# How to link module located at another folder?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I have the following structure of folders:

```
bulkloader (dir)
  - bulkloader.yaml
  - upload_data.cmd
app.yaml
models.py
```

How should I refer to models.py in bulkloader.yaml?

```
- import: models
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your models.py?

Comment: @Sologoub, Here I would like to transform data on import... something like `import_transform: models.transform(x)`